# Prevent automatic column sort after cell edit in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I add a new row or edit a cell, the row immediately disappears from view when sort is applied. I want to prevent this. How to go about it?

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a collection of DataRowViews.

Answer (score -1):

Set the property for the data grid AutoGenerateColumns="True"  , it will allows to update the data grid.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Comment: I don't want it to continue sorting after I add rows/ edit cells.